# PHP 500 (Internal Server Error) - A non-numeric value was encountered?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to have a autocomplete search input with jQuery and Laravel. But I'm getting an error when the user write at least 2 letters in the search input:

```
GET http://proj.test/autocomplete-search?term=ca 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Do you know where is the issue? I want to show the conferences based on the letters inserted by the user in the search form.

The search input:

```
<div class="col col-md-6">
    <h4 class="text-white  text-center font-weight-bold">Search</h4>
    <form class="main-search">
        <input type="text" id="search" class="autocomplete dropdown-toggle" placeholder="Conference, Citiy, Category">
    </form>
</div>
```

Laravel routes:

```
Route::get('/autocomplete-search', 'AutocompleteController@search');
```

Laravel AutomcompleteController:

```
class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{
    public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request->term;
        $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $data= [];
        foreach ($conferences as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['id'=>$value->id, 'value' => $value->id + " " + $value->name];
        }

        //dd($data);
        return response($data);
    }
}
```

jquery:

```
$("#search").autocomplete({
   source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}",
   minLength: 2,
   select:function(key, value)
   {
       console.log(value);
   }
});
```

EDIT: In the Network tab the error shows as:

> {message: "A non-numeric value encountered", exception:
>   "ErrorException",…}

and points to this line:

> {function: "search", class: "App\Http\Controllers\AutocompleteController", type: "->"}". In "$data[] = ['id'=>$value->id, 'value' => $value->id + " " + $value->name];

Comment: A 500 response means it's a server-side error, i.e. the server code crashed for some reason. It doesn't give away any more details to the client in case it inadvertently reveals something which an attacker could make use of (e.g. database details or something). So you have to check the server logs to find out the real error, and then it'll be easier to know how to fix it.

Comment: Your input field doesn't have a name, so PHP has no clue what you mean with `$request->term`. This is probably the error.

Comment: Something brief that strikes me though: `' value' => $value->name + " " + $value->name` -- firstly there's a space before "value" which probably shouldn't be there and secondly why are you concatenating the name twice? Did you mean to write `'value' => $value->id + " " + $value->name` perhaps? I doubt it's the source of the error but it just stood out as I was reading.

Comment: @Loek look at the reported URL at the start of the question - it seems to be sending the "term" parameter quite happily on the querystring.

Comment: Thanks, but same error with "            $data[] = ['id'=>$value->id, 'value' => $value->id + " " + $value->name];
".

Comment: "same error"....you haven't found the error yet! All you have is the generic 500 response. As I said I wasn't claiming to have found the fix. You need to go and find the real error message in the server logs.

Comment: @MarcinMagdziarz look at the reported URL at the start of the question - it seems to be going to the URL defined in the route quite happily.

Comment: The jquery is in the same page of the search input.

Comment: @ADyson Ah yeah, missed that! Then it's indeed a matter of checking the Laravel and/or server logs and see if those help pinpointing the problem.

Comment: It appears in network tab "{message: "A non-numeric value encountered", exception: "ErrorException",…}.

Comment: does it give a line number? If not then the stack trace in the logs should give one. Presumably somewhere there's a field which should contain a number but does not

Comment: It appears "
{function: "search", class: "App\Http\Controllers\AutocompleteController", type: "->"}". In "$data[] = ['id'=>$value->id, 'value' => $value->id + " " + $value->name];".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've used the addition operator (`+`) when you need to use the string concatenation operator (`.`).

So

```
$data[] = ['id'=>$value->id, ' value' => $value->id + " " + $value->name]
```

needs to become

```
$data[] = ['id'=> $value->id, 'value' => $value->id . " " . $value->name]
```

otherwise PHP thinks you're trying to do addition on these fields, when in fact they're text which you want to place into a single variable.

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php for info about which operators do what in PHP.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why for example if the user writes "co" and there is a conference with name "conf" in the database it appears in the autocomplete "conf conf" instead of just "conf"?

Comment: Probably because of what I mentioned in my earlier comments - "'value' => $value->name . " " . $value->name" is repeating the name twice in the output. Did you mean "'value' => $value->id . " " . $value->name" perhaps? I will edit my answer (as I edited your question) to reflect that change.